# Can I disable Navigationlink for a specified set of cells in my SwiftUI list?

Tags: swiftui-navigationlink

I am working on a contacts app in SwiftUI for work which will display hundreds of phone numbers. Some contacts have a detail view with address and alternate numbers, while some contacts do not.
For example, Harry Smith will have basic phone extension listed in row while his cell number and address are listed in detail view. 
But the number for the Second Floor Bathroom only needs the basic phone extension in the row, a detail view containing cell number and address for the bathroom is unnecessary.
How do I disable navigation link for those contacts who do not have pertinent detail info?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add NavigationLink on condition.
I will have a "Cell" with some contents. (image/file detail)

A - build a "content" View:

```
   struct MediumFileContentRow: View {

    var file: MediumFile

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            let (name, attribs) = file.getInfo() // get from model..
            Text(name)
            Spacer()
            Text(attribs)
        }// VStack
    }
}
```

B - Your cell (MediumFileRow) will conditionally add link (NavigationLink) "around" our content view, and will give back different Views using  **AnyView**:

```
struct MediumFileRow: View {
    var file: MediumFile


var body: some View {
        let enabled = NavigationLink(destination: Detail(t: file.name!)) {
            MediumFileContentRow(file: file)
        }
        let disabled = MediumFileContentRow(file: file)
        
        return file.isEmpty ? AnyView(disabled) : AnyView(enabled)

    }
```

All (almoast..) The code:

```
struct MediumFileContentRow: View {
    var file: MediumFile

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            let (s,sd) = file.displayed()
            Text(s)
            Spacer()
            Text(sd).font(.system(size: 9.0))
        }// VStack
    }
}


struct MediumFileRow: View {
    var file: MediumFile
    
    var body: some View {
        let enabled = NavigationLink(destination: Detail(t: file.name!)) {
            MediumFileContentRow(file: file)
        }
        let disabled = MediumFileContentRow(file: file)
        
        return file.isEmpty ? AnyView(disabled) : AnyView(enabled)

    }
    ...
```

..
In list You will have:

```
var body: some View {

NavigationView{
....


 List {
                    ForEach(mediumFiles, id: \.self) { file in
                        MediumFileRow(file: file)
                    }
                }
```

......

advantage: You can easily customise "disabled" cells.